# Concatenating single characters separated by white space in Java?

Tags: java

How can I write the logic to concatenate all the single latter separated by white space in Java?
For example String "a b c corporation" should be result in "abc corporation".

Comment: +1.At first sight it seems very easy but it's not so.Good question.

Comment: If you're using it for business names, you might need to consider punctuation too. For example `J.P. Morgan`, `J. P. Morgan` and `J P Morgan` are all common ways of writing that business name but they'll all come out differently with an algorithm that only considers whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving pointers - please code yourself !

1. use string.split[] on space char.
2. Use a StringBuilder
3. loop On the array you get from split

   3.1 if the value is of lenght 1, append to SB

   3.2 if the value is >1 lenght, append with a space in SB.

Comment: this doesn't work, because from "a b cde f g" you will get "abcde fg"

Comment: you probably have to fine tune the code to add space before and after the string having length >1. Also be aware that if such string is the last element then a space before it is enough. All the best.

Comment: @PetarIvanov:  Yeah,there has to be some fine tuning. I just wanted to give the OP an idea, its good learning for him if he takes care of details to make it work !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex replace with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
    String orig = "a b c corporation d e f";

    String replaced = orig.replaceAll("(?<=(^| )[a-zA-Z]) +(?=[a-zA-Z]( |$))", "");
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly: `a b c corporation` becomes `a bc corporation` — there is still a space after the first letter.

Comment: Its giving the output for "a b c corporation d e f" as "abc corporation def" It's missing something.

Comment: @gutch: Thanks! I fixed it - it was missing the fact that the single character might be at the start or at the end of the string.

Comment: @ sjain: Isn't that the desired output "a b c corporation d e f" -> "abc corporation def" ?

Comment: @Petar yes the same was desired and it is now giving same output. thanks